# How to get a "true" copy of protected member in base class

Tags: c++, oop

A base class has a protected shared_ptr member `var_` which is used as a local variable, the pointing type is a very complex struct. Now I have a derived class, it needs to iteratively modify `*var_`, but at the beginning of each iteration, I want `*var_` is exactly the same as I called the constructor of derived class. I can only call the derived class constructor once in the main function.

So the question is, how can I reset this `*var_` for each iteration, such that the modification in the previous iteration won't impact the following iterations. Now I can only make the iteration for just one time, since I'm using pass by reference, in the second iteration, I don't know how to reset it, so some overlying modification crashes the program.

I've tried pass by value simply. But I have to use lots of helper maps, which are located in the base class, for writing my derived class functions. Every time I use them, the generated data is associated with `*var`, but not the copied object in my derived class.

Please note I can't modify the base class too much, like converting the local member to member function parameters, etc.

If the local member variable is a simple container, like std::vector, I can simply reset it at the beginning of each iteration, and fill it inside the iteration later. I want the shared_ptr `var_` does the similar thing, or even better, make a "true" copy of it, since it's relatively big, and generating it needs some time, such that I can use the original one in each iteration, can I ?

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want a virtual `clone()` method. In general, if you have a `Base` pointer and don't know the actual derived class, you can only create a new `Base` object (slicing). The `clone` pattern requires cooperation from each derived class, because they do know their own identities. Still, that's just a matter of doing `return new Derived(*this)`